# kivy pip install fails saying not a git repository

Tags: git, pip, kivy

I am installing kivy following the standard instructions [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html). I have done this on another windows machine and it all worked. But now everything works until I get to the actual kivy install `python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1`. I get this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-83d5u9u6\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-83d5u9u6\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-up29odj0'
         cwd: C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-83d5u9u6\kivy\
    Complete output (396 lines):
    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    WARNING: Skipping page https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip because the HEAD request got Content-Type: application/zip.The only supported Content-Type is text/html
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-74p8k0mj\\cython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-74p8k0mj\\cython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-y60trwec'
           cwd: C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-74p8k0mj\cython\
```

I think the heart of the error message is the line *fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git*

Can anyone suggest what is going on here and how to fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Python 3.8 and there is no wheel created for Python 3.8. So, it tries to compile from the source and fails. If you want to use Kivy 1.11.1 release, then you need Python release <= 3.7. Or else you can use Kivy release 2.0.0rc3.